# Installing Heroku cli on archlinux using snapd :command not found

Tags: heroku, archlinux, manjaro, heroku-cli

I have installed heroku cli following their ref https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

using snapd on Manjaro arch-based linux distro

It was installed successfully and just to make sure

When I run this cmd

```
sudo snap install heroku
```

I get

```
snap "heroku" is already installed, see "snap refresh --help"
```

but when I try to verify the CLI installation using this cmd

```
heroku --version
```

I get

```
bash: heroku: command not found
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Try rebooting system and then using heroku commands.

Comment: try this `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Comment: Rebooting the system worked for me (although logging out and back in would probably have sufficed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally means that the directory in which you have installed your package is not included in your $PATH.

Look at the output of

```
echo $PATH
```

and export the path of the directory containing heroku's executable if it's not already included.

Read more about exporting paths [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables).

You might want to source your .bashrc file (or .zshrc if you are on ZSH) after exporting.

To check if the export is successful, you can type in `which heroku`and confirm the same.

Cheers!

Comment: `heroku` is installed at `/snap/bin` so add that to your PATH

Answer (score 2):

You can run like this:

```
    snap run heroku
```

Examples:

```
    snap run heroku --version
    snap run heroku login -i
```

Answer (score 1):

I have heroku just installed using snap and had the same issue. Also, I noticed that I could run heroku using **sudo**.

The executable was placed in /snap/bin/heroku, so i just did this (considering /usr/bin is already in $PATH):

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/heroku /usr/bin/heroku
```

Since I had previously run heroku with sudo, the directory ~/.cache/heroku/ , owned by root, was created. So I got an error message when first ran the command as non-root:

```
Error Plugin: heroku: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/carlos.brasileiro/.cache/heroku/lastrun'
```

I removed that ~/.cache/heroku/ and it got ok.